# Cassandra CQL : insert data from existing file

Tags: cassandra

I have a JSON file that I want to insert into a Cassandra table using CQL.

According to datastax documentation, you can insert json with the following command :

```
INSERT INTO data JSON '{My_Json}';
```

But I can't find a way to do that directly from an existing json file. Is this possible or do I need to to some Java code to do that insert ?

Note : I am using Cassandra 3.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only file format supported for importing is csv. It is possible to convert your json file to CSV format and import it with the [copy command](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCopy.html). If that is not an option for you, java code is needed to parse your file and insert it into Cassandra.

Comment: I already have a json->csv converter so this is a good solution for me, thanks a lot.